# Alternative for matches() in Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching, match

In SQL, we have pattern matching operator `like` with "`_`" and "`%`" to search for a string, or a part of a string.
Is there anything similar to that in Java.
There is the `matches()` method. However, that only returns `true` if the entire `String` matches the regex.
I need a method that can evaluate if a given `String` exists in another `String` as a part of it.

Comment: `"_" and "%` are not `pattern matching operators`. That are wildcards

Comment: dear , you want `contains`

Comment: *only returns true if the entire string matches the regex* No. It Returns true if the string mataches the regex. you can use dot for every character. Something like `.*HELLO World.*`  will match also `HELLO World i am here`

Comment: @Jens it is worth mentioning that by default `.` doesn't match line terminators so this will not work with multi-line text. To solve this problem we can use DOTALL flag (we can place `(?s)` at start of regex), or instead of `.` use sum of set and its negation like `[\s\S]` to represent all characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a SQL like 'LIKE' operator in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898405/how-to-implement-a-sql-like-like-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Check the contains method of the String class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: Not for regex, only for static Strings. Worth mentioning :)

Answer (score 1):

*contains* is not usable if you need to perform regex matching.

You can trick the *matches()* method to behave as you expect, just saying that you want whatever sequence of character at start and end of the string.

Nice solution is to use **matcher.find()** which looks for occurrences of the regex. Look at class [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **String.Contains()**

Example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s = "Hello World";

    System.out.print(s.contains("Wor")); //return true
    System.out.print(s.contains("wor")); //return false beacuse is case-sensitive
  }
```