# Android + ObjectBox Search Query Issue

Tags: android, search, android-database, objectbox

I am stuck with the **ObjectBox** Like Query. I have done as below when I search for something.

```
    QueryBuilder<MItemDetail> builder = mItemDetailListBox.query();
    builder.contains(MItemDetail_.productName, search);
    itemList = builder.build().find();
```

For example, My data is:

1. paracetamol
2. paracetamol potest
3. paracetamol_new

#### Problem:

Now as you know the **contains** works simply as that returns a list of items that contain a given search string.

#### What I Want:

- If I search **para new**, I want the result **paracetamol_new**
- If I search **para p**, I want the result **paracetamol potest**
- If I search **para e e**, I want the result **paracetamol potest** and **paracetamol_new**

Is there any function or utility available in ObjectBox that can help me to achieve this?

Do let me know If you have any questions.

#### Edited:

The given links in a comment, My question is different. I know all the methods `contains()`, `startsWith`, and `endsWith` but my problem not getting solved using that.

Comment: Would `startsWith()` help in your case? Please describe your issue with `contains()` more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: If I give space between words, the `contains()` is not giving proper results as I mentioned. I want something like `%yourWords%yourwords%` (given example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ObjectBox have a SQL Like keyword equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846019/does-objectbox-have-a-sql-like-keyword-equivalent)

Comment: See the solutions for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846019/does-objectbox-have-a-sql-like-keyword-equivalent

Comment: I don't think that it will work for me because I don't need `startWith` and `endsWith`, I want to find from in between too.

Comment: filter() was also mentioned there. See https://docs.objectbox.io/queries#query-filters for details. If possible, combine this with startsWith().

Comment: @MarkusJunginger Finally I did that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MarkusJunginger I got the solution as below. It's taking time to load it. Can you give me any efficient way to search from 100k products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51846371/1318946) I have done some changes as given and I got a perfect solution as I wanted.

```
QueryBuilder<MItemDetail> builder = mItemDetailListBox.query();
// builder.contains(MItemDetail_.productName, search);
builder.filter(new QueryFilter<MItemDetail>() {
    @Override
    public boolean keep(@NonNull MItemDetail entity) {
        return like(entity.getProductName(), "%"+ search + "%");
    }
}).order(MItemDetail_.productName);
businessModels = builder.build().find();
```

In the following methods, I have added one more replace statement `.replace(" ",".*?")`

```
private static boolean like(final String str, final String expr) {
    String safeString = (str == null) ? "" : str;
    String regex = quoteMeta(expr);
    regex = regex.replace("_", ".").replace(" ",".*?").replace("%", ".*?");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex,
            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    return p.matcher(safeString).matches();
}

private static String quoteMeta(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String cannot be null");
    }

    int len = s.length();
    if (len == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if ("[](){}.*+?$^|#\\".indexOf(c) != -1) {
            sb.append("\\");
        }
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Thank you.