# How to use regular expression in ObjectBox

Tags: android, objectbox

I want to implement regular expression in `ObjectBox` database. Something like -

```
Query<User> query = userBox.query().like(User_.firstName, "J*e?").build();
List<User> users = query.find();
query.close();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ObjectBox have a SQL Like keyword equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846019/does-objectbox-have-a-sql-like-keyword-equivalent)

Comment: @RickyMo No, actually. The regex `J*e?` would search for `Joe`, `Je` and `Joel`