# JAVA - LIKE OPERATOR

Tags: java, spring

I would like to use LIKE in Java. How can you get the same functionality in Java that I offer function LIKE in sql. I use Cassandra and SpringData does not LIKE operator. 
EXAMPLE:

Input data: dog

Output that satisfies the condition : dogabc, abcddog, abdogd

Comment: you can write your own like method.

Comment: I guess String#contains should do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a SQL like 'LIKE' operator in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898405/how-to-implement-a-sql-like-like-operator-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case you could just write `string.contains("dog")`, however if you need something a little more complicated you can look at String similarity libraries.

Here are some good pointers: [How can I detect common substrings in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410822/how-can-i-detect-common-substrings-in-a-list-of-strings/)