# How to replace recurring pattern with same delimitter to open and close the pattern?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Searched all over to find out how to replace quoted values in Strings.
(I expected this to be a common requirement!)

Considered this simple example:

```
        String test1 = "This is a string with a \"dog\" and a \"cat\" that are unwanted.";
        System.out.println(test1);
        System.out.println(test1.replaceAll("\".*\"", "ZAPPED"));
```

produces:

```
This is a string with a "dog" and a "cat" that are unwanted.
This is a string with a ZAPPED that are unwanted.
```

But I wanted:

```
This is a string with a ZAPPED and a ZAPPED that are unwanted.
```

I expected the pattern matching to stop at the second quote (at least in replaceAll()).

Comment: Use `.*?` instead of `.*` `test1.replaceAll("\".*?\"", "ZAPPED")` Using `.*` is a greedy capture due to which it captures all characters and captures all text in between two doublequotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix my regex to not match too much with a greedy quantifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255815/how-can-i-fix-my-regex-to-not-match-too-much-with-a-greedy-quantifier)

Comment: Ah! Of course - just too simple!
Thank you!